# how to display complete Bitmap in android using Canvas?

Tags: android

friends,

i am using following onDraw method to display bitmap on screen.

```
 @Override
            public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                    Bitmap _scratch =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon2);

                    //ImageView img= new ImageView(Tutorial2D.this);
                    //img.setImageBitmap(_scratch);
                    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

                    canvas.drawBitmap(_scratch, 0, 0, null);


            }
```

image is displayed on the screen but some part because android screen is small
how can i display complete image in whole android screen?

can i set ScaleType of image to fitxy in canvas ?

or

can i add android layout image to this canvas so that i could set fitxy property or image there as i have commented the code?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a ImageView

```
iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
iv.setImageBitmap(getImageBitmap(myurl));
```

Comment: You might want to setScaleType to fitXY

Comment: ImageView are automatic scaled

Comment: Ah - now I understand the question better. UMMA is looking to replicate that functionality with a canvas.